Inconsistent Movement Behaviour between built Game and Playmode
I'm using a simple MonoBehaviour that causes GameObjects to change their position based on a Vector2 consisting of a Mathf.Sin() and Mathf.Cos() function, this works pretty well when in playmode, but whenever I build the game, the movement behaviour is way off from the playmode.
The script I'm using is independent from the rest of my code, so if you want to test it yourself, it should work.
The specific case I have been messing around with uses the following settings:
Sin Multiplier = 1
Cos Multiplier = 1
Effect Strength = 0.001
I'm just using a 2D GameObject with a square SpriteRenderer and the script attached to it, test it in play mode and then build the game and the square should move slower and in a drastically reduced range.
I'm guessing this has something to do with the code being frame rate dependent, but I don't know how that would be possible with this code.
public sealed class ObjectWobbleEffect : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Settings:")]
    [SerializeField] private float _sinMultiplier;
    [SerializeField] private float _cosMultiplier;
    [SerializeField] private float _effectStrength;

    private float _currentTime;

    private void Update() =>
        transform.position += (Vector3)ExecuteEffect();

    private Vector2 ExecuteEffect()
    {
        const float Cycle = Mathf.PI * 2f;

        _currentTime += Time.deltaTime;

        if(_currentTime >= Cycle)
            Mathf.Repeat(_currentTime, Cycle);

        return new Vector2(Mathf.Sin(_currentTime * _sinMultiplier), Mathf.Cos(_currentTime * _cosMultiplier)) * _effectStrength;
    }
}


The root of your issue is you're updating the position of this object using Euler's method.
That is, you have a function that computes velocity given a time input, and you're numerically integrating it to find the position at that time. You're doing this slightly incorrectly though, since each frame you're applying 1 full second's worth of velocity to the position regardless of the time interval, instead of scaling it by the timestep:
transform.position += (Vector3)ExecuteEffect();

should be
transform.position += (Vector3)(ExecuteEffect() * Time.deltaTime);

(And you'd scale up your effect strength to compensate for the smaller increments you get this way)
But the more fundamental issue is that Euler integration kind of sucks.
It's trying to predict where the object should be in the future using only one instantaneous sample of where it's going now, so it only gives exactly correct results if the velocity is constant. If acceleration is constant, it parallels the correct trajectory but offset in time. And if acceleration is varying, as in the case here, the Euler integrated trajectory will always diverge from the true trajectory, and diverge faster when the time step is larger.
For this particular effect, you can do the integration via math instead:
$$
\frac {d \vec p} {d t} = \left( \sin(f_s t), \cos(f_c t)\right) s_E\\
\vec p = \vec p_0 + \int_0^t \left( \sin(f_s x), \cos(f_c x)\right) s_E  dx\\
= \vec p_0 + s_E  \left( \frac {-\cos(f_s x)} {f_s}, \frac {\sin(f_c x)} {f_c}\right) \bigg\rvert^t_0\\
= \vec p_0 + s_E \left( \frac {1 - \cos(f_s t)} {f_s}, \frac {\sin(f_c t)} {f_c} \right)
$$
Now we have an explicit formula for the position at a given time, which works completely independently of any simulation tick rate.
Converting this to code would look like this:
private Vector2 GetUpdatedPosition() {
    const float cycle = Mathf.PI * 2f;

    // If you want to apply a different time scale to each term,
    // then you need to apply the wrapping to them separately.
    _sinPhase = (_sinPhase + Time.deltaTime * _sinMultiplier) % cycle; 
    _cosPhase = (_cosPhase + Time.deltaTime * _cosMultiplier) % cycle; 

    // Because these were sin and cos terms respectively in the velocity,
    // they change to cos and sin in the position. You might want to
    // rename the variables to make this less confusing. I've kept them
    // named as-is here so they have the same effect as your current code.
    var shift = new Vector2( 
                 (1f - Mathf.Cos(_sinPhase))/_sinMultiplier,
                 Mathf.Sin(_cosPhase)/_cosMultiplier
    );

    return _startPosition + _effectStrength * shift;
}

// No more +=
// We're not accumulating a velocity, we're jumping straight to
// the correct position for this time.
private void Update() =>
        transform.position = GetUpdatedPosition();

This will still accumulate small rounding errors in the phase variables because we're summing up lots of small time steps, but that floating point error is much much smaller than the integration error you had before. You'll observe the correct-looking trajectory, it's just not guaranteed to be perfectly synched with a copy of the same code running at a different framerate, since the two clocks can drift slightly. But by keeping the calculation close to zero, we don't have to worry about degrading precision if this runs for hours or days on end.

I see a couple of problems.
Framerate dependent behavior
There are also a couple of things I see with the update function itself.
For physics and physics-related concerns, use FixedUpdate
Unlike Update, which has a variable timestep which depends on framerate, FixedUpdate has a fixed timestep. Notably, Unity's built-in physics system operates on these Fixed timesteps rather than the framerate dependent ones.
Since your code is doing physics-like things (moving position with respect to time), it should use FixedUpdate.
Do not approximate time as a sum of deltaTime
In the land of pure mathematics, the sum of Time.deltaTime from start until the current time would equal the current time. However, IEEE Floating Point Numbers are not pure mathematics, and the sum of delta time will usually end up slightly off from the current time.
I recommend instead Time.time instead of accumulating everything in _currentTime. If you want to be invariant across scene resets, you can capture the current time at the start of the scene in Start, and then compute float TimeSinceSceneStarted = Time.time - this._timeAtStart.
Mathf.Repeat used incorrectly
There are two issues with the way that you are using Mathf.Repeat - thankfully, at the moment, these issues are cancelling eachother out and resulting in correct behavior. However, if you fix one of these issues without fixing the other, you could suddenly incorrect behavior despite the change itself being correct.
One problem is that your inputs to Mathf.Sin and Mathf.Cos are first repeated to 2Pi then scaled. This can result in teleportation - for example, if your _sinMultiplier is 0.25f, then every 6.29 seconds, the object will teleport from x=1 to x=0.
However, the other problem is that you are discarding the results of Mathf.Repeat rather than assigning them into the stored value. A correct invocation would be _currentTime = Mathf.Repeat(_currentTime, Cycle);.
I recommend removing the Mathf.Repeat call entirely, as it isn't doing anything at the moment, and would only be doing harm if it were.

Careful, Time.time also suffers from floating point precision limitations, and will lose precision the longer the game runs. It you're just making a demo that will run for a few minutes it's fine, but if you want to scale up to a full game that can be paused/suspended and resumed for combined play sessions spanning multiple days, this will bite you. Generally we want to avoid doing frame-by-frame calculations from a total time float, though if you have to, Time.timeAsDouble keeps usable precision for centuries.
